# Cannot run junit tests in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, intellij-14

I am trying to run some junit tests within Intellij 14 on Windows 7.  I have run these tests before, many many times, without issue.

Yesterday, I started getting the error on SOME tests only:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: package xxx is sealed
```

I cannot google up a satisfactory answer to this.  I initially thought it was something odd that suddenly went wrong in intellij 15, so I reverted back to 14 (cleaned up the settings folder too) but same issue.

Same tests, run from Linux using an ant script and the same jar file run just fine.

What does this error mean and what must I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could have a class that is being packed into multiple jar. Do you have a **production** jar and maybe a **test** jar which share some class between them?

Comment: I do not, there is just the one jar file.

Comment: I'm really confused now.  If I have a junit test, defined in "package a/b/c/d", using a method from a class in "package a/b/c", I am seeing the failure.  If, OTOH, a test in "package a/b/c" references the same method, it works fine.  This is only occuring in IntelliJ - commandline from linux works fine.  The manifest for the jar has "Sealed: true" at the top, but it's been that way for a loong time and I've run these tests many times. The rest of the manifest just lists class files.

Comment: So, it would appear that you were on the right track after all.  I didn't have multiple jars, but, I did find a situation where a singleton was instantiated in a parameterization block (of a junit test), then the same call was made again in the class's constructor (long-standing code).  I don't understand why that would have led to the sealing error on windows (it worked fine on linux), but removing the call in the parameterization block cleared up the error.  Would you have an idea as to why this would have been an error?

Comment: Could there be multiple jars because you are building one with maven/ant and also building one with eclipse/intellij? In the end, there are two entries on your classpath which point to the same class/package which is sealed.

Comment: The jar is only built via ant... I don't have a build for the jar in intellij.